# Using a windows.dll in a Xamarin project to deploy on an iPad

Tags: xcode, ipad, dll, xamarin, dynamic-linking

I have a C# library that I want to use in my Xamarin project to deploy to an iPad.

Lets suppose the C# library is stored as MyUtilities.dll.

For a regular Windows app, I'd add MyUtilities.dll to my project Resources and then have a

```
using MyUtilities;
```

statement in the class where I wanted to use classes from that library.

How do I accomplish this same thing using Xamarin in an iPad app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to rebuild your library from the source using the Xamarin.iOS compiler.  After that you would reference the same way you do in a Windows app - by either including a Reference to the dll in your project, or by including the Library project in your solution and referencing the project.

Comment: I don't have access to all the source code.  We wrote the .dll, but it uses a com library from Microsoft to implement uPnp.  We are not allowed access to the source code from that microsoft library.  Are we out of luck, or is there still a way to do this.

Comment: Do you mean COM "Component Access Model"?  If so, there is no way that will run on iOS.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes..  We are were going to use it because it implements uPnp.  However, there are other open source possibilities, so we'll go that way instead.  Then we can have access to all source code and build it with the Xamarin.iOS compiler.  Thanks for your help!